# How to export mysql databases from one linux pc to another linux pc without installing additional software?

Tags: mysql, database, export

I have mysql database in one pc but now i want to do my work on another pc.It is not possible for me to write sql queries once again because it is very time consuming.What should I do ?

Comment: You can use phpmyadmin, it is easy to use here I leave you a tutorial on how to do it :) https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/export-database-using-phpmyadmin

Comment: 'It is not possible for me to write sql queries once again' - what queries are you talking about? Also read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html

Comment: Ya it is possible using phpmyadmin, but we have to install phpmyadmin and then we do exporting or importing of database.So to get rid of that we are just using mysqldump functionality of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Exporting MySQL database from one pc to another pc**
```

1. Open linux terminal and type following commands to open mysql terminal

**mysqldump -u "username" -p databaseName > "path where we have to .sql file for exporting" databaseName.sql**

**e.g. mysqldump -u root -p akashgudadhe.db > /Documents/sky/akashgudadhe.sql**

it will export your mysql database to your Documents/sky directory.

```
    **Importing MySQL database from one pc to another pc**
```

1.Open linux terminal and type following command to open mysql terminal

**mysql -u "userName" -p** //Enter password for your mysql username.

**e.g mysql -u root -p //hit enter key.**

it will open mysql terminal.

2. To import any database first we have to create blank database.

**create database "databaseName"; //databaseName without " " quotes
use "databaseName";**

**for. e.g. create database akashgudadhe;
use akashgudadhe**

3. Importing required databases from .sql file which we have to import in our mysql database.

**source "directoryFor.sqlFolder" "databaseName.sql";
for e.g. source /Documents/akashgudadhe.sql**

//databaseName.sql file is the file which we want to import in our mysql database